# How to put data from data base to Ext.FormPanel?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Ext.FormPanel with textfielda and i want to show data in this fields. In sencha site i see a example how to do this http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/xml-form.html . But they use ExtJs 4.1 but i have only ExtJS 3.4. And when i try repide this example firebug says that `Ext.define is not a function`. Also i cant find `Ext.data.Model` in API on sencha site.
So its possible make something like this with ExtJs 3.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's exactly the same example in Ext 3:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/form/xml-form.html

Comment: Yeah i really dumb. Find it minute ago.